# Android SDK/NDK error with python-for-android/kivy

Tags: android, python, android-ndk, kivy, android-sdk-tools

I'm on Fedora Linux 19, using the latest Android SDK, latest java SDK, and NDK=R9. Using the instructions [here](http://kivy.org/docs/guide/packaging-android.html#packaging-android), I'm trying to create a python/kivy installation specialized for android, by running the command, `./distribute.sh -m "kivy"`. It produces the output below. Can anyone tell me what's going wrong here, and what I can do to fix it? Thank you.

```
./dist*sh -m "kivy"

Check build dependencies for Fedora
Avoid check build dependencies, unknow platform Fedora
Check enviromnent
SDK located at /home/ljm/Developer/android-sdks
NDK located at /home/ljm/Developer/android-ndk-r9
NDK version is r9
API level set to 18
Check mandatory tools
Distribution will be located at /home/ljm/Developer/workspace/python-for-android/dist/default
The distribution /home/ljm/Developer/workspace/python-for-android/dist/default already exist
Press a key to remove it, or Control + C to abort.

Entering in ARM enviromnent
Compiler found at /home/ljm/Developer/android-ndk-r9/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc
PATH is /home/ljm/Developer/android-ndk-r9/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/:/home/ljm/Developer/android-ndk-r9/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/:/home/ljm/Developer/android-ndk-r9:/home/ljm/Developer/android-sdks/tools:/home/ljm/Developer/android-ndk-r9:/home/ljm/Developer/android-ndk-r9/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/:/home/ljm/Developer/android-sdks:/home/ljm/Developer/android-sdks/platform-tools:/home/ljm/Developer/android-sdks/tools:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/homeljm.local/bin:/homeljmbin
Leaving ARM enviromnent
Read kivy recipe
Module kivy depend on pygame pyjnius android
Read pygame recipe
Module pygame depend on python sdl
Read pyjnius recipe
Module pyjnius depend on python sdl
Read android recipe
Module android depend on pygame
Read python recipe
Module python depend on hostpython
Read sdl recipe
Module sdl depend on python
Ignored python, already processed
Ignored sdl, already processed
Ignored pygame, already processed
Read hostpython recipe
Ignored python, already processed
Modules changed to hostpython python sdl pygame pyjnius android kivy
Run get packages
Download package for hostpython
Module hostpython already downloaded
Download package for python
Module python already downloaded
Download package for sdl
No package for sdl
Download package for pygame
Module pygame already downloaded
Download package for pyjnius
Module pyjnius already downloaded
Download package for android
No package for android
Download package for kivy
Module kivy already downloaded
Run prebuild
Call prebuild_hostpython
Call prebuild_python
Call prebuild_sdl
Call prebuild_pygame
Call prebuild_pyjnius
Call prebuild_android
Call prebuild_kivy
Run build
Call build_hostpython
Call build_python
Call build_sdl
Entering in ARM enviromnent
Compiler found at /home/ljm/Developer/android-ndk-r9/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc
Android NDK: WARNING:/home/ljm/Developer/workspace/python-for-android/src/jni/../jni/application/Android.mk:application: non-system libraries in linker flags: -lpython2.7    
Android NDK:     This is likely to result in incorrect builds. Try using LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES    
Android NDK:     or LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES instead to list the library dependencies of the    
Android NDK:     current module    
Android NDK: WARNING:/home/ljm/Developer/workspace/python-for-android/src/jni/../jni/png/Android.mk:png: LOCAL_LDLIBS is always ignored for static libraries    
rm -f /home/ljm/Developer/workspace/python-for-android/src/libs/armeabi/lib*.so /home/ljm/Developer/workspace/python-for-android/src/libs/armeabi-v7a/lib*.so /home/ljm/Developer/workspace/python-for-android/src/libs/mips/lib*.so /home/ljm/Developer/workspace/python-for-android/src/libs/x86/lib*.so
rm -f /home/ljm/Developer/workspace/python-for-android/src/libs/armeabi/gdbserver /home/ljm/Developer/workspace/python-for-android/src/libs/armeabi-v7a/gdbserver /home/ljm/Developer/workspace/python-for-android/src/libs/mips/gdbserver /home/ljm/Developer/workspace/python-for-android/src/libs/x86/gdbserver
rm -f /home/ljm/Developer/workspace/python-for-android/src/libs/armeabi/gdb.setup /home/ljm/Developer/workspace/python-for-android/src/libs/armeabi-v7a/gdb.setup /home/ljm/Developer/workspace/python-for-android/src/libs/mips/gdb.setup /home/ljm/Developer/workspace/python-for-android/src/libs/x86/gdb.setup
Install        : libapplication.so => libs/armeabi/libapplication.so
install -p /home/ljm/Developer/workspace/python-for-android/src/obj/local/armeabi/libapplication.so /home/ljm/Developer/workspace/python-for-android/src/libs/armeabi/libapplication.so
/home/ljm/Developer/android-ndk-r9/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-strip --strip-unneeded  /home/ljm/Developer/workspace/python-for-android/src/libs/armeabi/libapplication.so
Install        : libsdl.so => libs/armeabi/libsdl.so
install -p /home/ljm/Developer/workspace/python-for-android/src/obj/local/armeabi/libsdl.so /home/ljm/Developer/workspace/python-for-android/src/libs/armeabi/libsdl.so
/home/ljm/Developer/android-ndk-r9/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-strip --strip-unneeded  /home/ljm/Developer/workspace/python-for-android/src/libs/armeabi/libsdl.so
Install        : libsdl_main.so => libs/armeabi/libsdl_main.so
install -p /home/ljm/Developer/workspace/python-for-android/src/obj/local/armeabi/libsdl_main.so /home/ljm/Developer/workspace/python-for-android/src/libs/armeabi/libsdl_main.so
/home/ljm/Developer/android-ndk-r9/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-strip --strip-unneeded  /home/ljm/Developer/workspace/python-for-android/src/libs/armeabi/libsdl_main.so
Install        : libsdl_ttf.so => libs/armeabi/libsdl_ttf.so
install -p /home/ljm/Developer/workspace/python-for-android/src/obj/local/armeabi/libsdl_ttf.so /home/ljm/Developer/workspace/python-for-android/src/libs/armeabi/libsdl_ttf.so
/home/ljm/Developer/android-ndk-r9/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-strip --strip-unneeded  /home/ljm/Developer/workspace/python-for-android/src/libs/armeabi/libsdl_ttf.so
Install        : libsdl_image.so => libs/armeabi/libsdl_image.so
install -p /home/ljm/Developer/workspace/python-for-android/src/obj/local/armeabi/libsdl_image.so /home/ljm/Developer/workspace/python-for-android/src/libs/armeabi/libsdl_image.so
/home/ljm/Developer/android-ndk-r9/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-strip --strip-unneeded  /home/ljm/Developer/workspace/python-for-android/src/libs/armeabi/libsdl_image.so
Install        : libsqlite3.so => libs/armeabi/libsqlite3.so
install -p /home/ljm/Developer/workspace/python-for-android/src/obj/local/armeabi/libsqlite3.so /home/ljm/Developer/workspace/python-for-android/src/libs/armeabi/libsqlite3.so
/home/ljm/Developer/android-ndk-r9/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-strip --strip-unneeded  /home/ljm/Developer/workspace/python-for-android/src/libs/armeabi/libsqlite3.so
Install        : libsdl_mixer.so => libs/armeabi/libsdl_mixer.so
install -p /home/ljm/Developer/workspace/python-for-android/src/obj/local/armeabi/libsdl_mixer.so /home/ljm/Developer/workspace/python-for-android/src/libs/armeabi/libsdl_mixer.so
/home/ljm/Developer/android-ndk-r9/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-strip --strip-unneeded  /home/ljm/Developer/workspace/python-for-android/src/libs/armeabi/libsdl_mixer.so
Leaving ARM enviromnent
Call build_pygame
Entering in ARM enviromnent
Compiler found at /home/ljm/Developer/android-ndk-r9/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc
running install
running build
running build_py
running build_ext
building 'pygame.surface' extension
arm-linux-androideabi-gcc -DANDROID -mandroid -fomit-frame-pointer --sysroot /home/ljm/Developer/android-ndk-r9/platforms/android-18/arch-arm -DNDEBUG -g -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -DANDROID -mandroid -fomit-frame-pointer --sysroot /home/ljm/Developer/android-ndk-r9/platforms/android-18/arch-arm -I/home/ljm/Developer/workspace/python-for-android/src/jni/png -I/home/ljm/Developer/workspace/python-for-android/src/jni/jpeg -I/home/ljm/Developer/workspace/python-for-android/src/jni/sdl/include -I/home/ljm/Developer/workspace/python-for-android/src/jni/sdl_mixer -I/home/ljm/Developer/workspace/python-for-android/src/jni/sdl_ttf -I/home/ljm/Developer/workspace/python-for-android/src/jni/sdl_image -fPIC -D_REENTRANT -I/home/ljm/Developer/workspace/python-for-android/build/python-install/include/python2.7 -c src/surface.c -o build/temp.linux-i686-2.7/src/surface.o
In file included from /home/ljm/Developer/workspace/python-for-android/build/python-install/include/python2.7/Python.h:126:0,
                 from src/pygame.h:75,
                 from src/surface.h:28,
                 from src/surface.c:26:
/home/ljm/Developer/workspace/python-for-android/build/python-install/include/python2.7/modsupport.h:27:1: warning: 'PyArg_ParseTuple' is an unrecognized format function type [-Wformat=]
 PyAPI_FUNC(int) PyArg_ParseTuple(PyObject *, const char *, ...) Py_FORMAT_PARSETUPLE(PyArg_ParseTuple, 2, 3);
 ^
src/surface.c: In function 'surf_get_locked':
src/surface.c:755:9: warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules [-Wstrict-aliasing]
         Py_RETURN_TRUE;
         ^
src/surface.c:756:5: warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules [-Wstrict-aliasing]
     Py_RETURN_FALSE;
     ^
src/surface.c: In function 'surf_convert_alpha':
src/surface.c:1279:28: warning: variable 'src' set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
     SDL_Surface *newsurf, *src;
                            ^
arm-linux-androideabi-gcc -DANDROID -mandroid -fomit-frame-pointer --sysroot /home/ljm/Developer/android-ndk-r9/platforms/android-18/arch-arm -DNDEBUG -g -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -DANDROID -mandroid -fomit-frame-pointer --sysroot /home/ljm/Developer/android-ndk-r9/platforms/android-18/arch-arm -I/home/ljm/Developer/workspace/python-for-android/src/jni/png -I/home/ljm/Developer/workspace/python-for-android/src/jni/jpeg -I/home/ljm/Developer/workspace/python-for-android/src/jni/sdl/include -I/home/ljm/Developer/workspace/python-for-android/src/jni/sdl_mixer -I/home/ljm/Developer/workspace/python-for-android/src/jni/sdl_ttf -I/home/ljm/Developer/workspace/python-for-android/src/jni/sdl_image -fPIC -D_REENTRANT -I/home/ljm/Developer/workspace/python-for-android/build/python-install/include/python2.7 -c src/alphablit.c -o build/temp.linux-i686-2.7/src/alphablit.o
In file included from /home/ljm/Developer/workspace/python-for-android/build/python-install/include/python2.7/Python.h:126:0,
                 from src/pygame.h:75,
                 from src/surface.h:28,
                 from src/alphablit.c:25:
/home/ljm/Developer/workspace/python-for-android/build/python-install/include/python2.7/modsupport.h:27:1: warning: 'PyArg_ParseTuple' is an unrecognized format function type [-Wformat=]
 PyAPI_FUNC(int) PyArg_ParseTuple(PyObject *, const char *, ...) Py_FORMAT_PARSETUPLE(PyArg_ParseTuple, 2, 3);
 ^
In file included from src/surface.h:28:0,
                 from src/alphablit.c:25:
src/pygame.h:678:14: warning: 'PyGAME_C_API' defined but not used [-Wunused-variable]
 static void* PyGAME_C_API[PYGAMEAPI_TOTALSLOTS] = { NULL };
              ^
arm-linux-androideabi-gcc -DANDROID -mandroid -fomit-frame-pointer --sysroot /home/ljm/Developer/android-ndk-r9/platforms/android-18/arch-arm -DNDEBUG -g -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -DANDROID -mandroid -fomit-frame-pointer --sysroot /home/ljm/Developer/android-ndk-r9/platforms/android-18/arch-arm -I/home/ljm/Developer/workspace/python-for-android/src/jni/png -I/home/ljm/Developer/workspace/python-for-android/src/jni/jpeg -I/home/ljm/Developer/workspace/python-for-android/src/jni/sdl/include -I/home/ljm/Developer/workspace/python-for-android/src/jni/sdl_mixer -I/home/ljm/Developer/workspace/python-for-android/src/jni/sdl_ttf -I/home/ljm/Developer/workspace/python-for-android/src/jni/sdl_image -fPIC -D_REENTRANT -I/home/ljm/Developer/workspace/python-for-android/build/python-install/include/python2.7 -c src/surface_fill.c -o build/temp.linux-i686-2.7/src/surface_fill.o
In file included from /home/ljm/Developer/workspace/python-for-android/build/python-install/include/python2.7/Python.h:126:0,
                 from src/pygame.h:75,
                 from src/surface.h:28,
                 from src/surface_fill.c:20:
/home/ljm/Developer/workspace/python-for-android/build/python-install/include/python2.7/modsupport.h:27:1: warning: 'PyArg_ParseTuple' is an unrecognized format function type [-Wformat=]
 PyAPI_FUNC(int) PyArg_ParseTuple(PyObject *, const char *, ...) Py_FORMAT_PARSETUPLE(PyArg_ParseTuple, 2, 3);
 ^
In file included from src/surface.h:28:0,
                 from src/surface_fill.c:20:
src/pygame.h:678:14: warning: 'PyGAME_C_API' defined but not used [-Wunused-variable]
 static void* PyGAME_C_API[PYGAMEAPI_TOTALSLOTS] = { NULL };
              ^
/home/ljm/Developer/workspace/python-for-android/src/tools/liblink -lm -L/home/ljm/Developer/workspace/python-for-android/build/libs -L/home/ljm/Developer/workspace/python-for-android/src/obj/local/armeabi/ -lm -lz -DANDROID -mandroid -fomit-frame-pointer --sysroot /home/ljm/Developer/android-ndk-r9/platforms/android-18/arch-arm -I/home/ljm/Developer/workspace/python-for-android/src/jni/png -I/home/ljm/Developer/workspace/python-for-android/src/jni/jpeg -I/home/ljm/Developer/workspace/python-for-android/src/jni/sdl/include -I/home/ljm/Developer/workspace/python-for-android/src/jni/sdl_mixer -I/home/ljm/Developer/workspace/python-for-android/src/jni/sdl_ttf -I/home/ljm/Developer/workspace/python-for-android/src/jni/sdl_image build/temp.linux-i686-2.7/src/surface.o build/temp.linux-i686-2.7/src/alphablit.o build/temp.linux-i686-2.7/src/surface_fill.o -L/home/ljm/Developer/workspace/python-for-android/build/python-install/lib -lsdl -lm -lpython2.7 -o build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/pygame/surface.so
arm-linux-androideabi-ld: -arch: unknown option
arm-linux-androideabi-ld: use the --help option for usage information
error: command '/home/ljm/Developer/workspace/python-for-android/src/tools/liblink' failed with exit status 1
```

Comment: The build chain has been successfully tested on api14, ndk r8d so any ndk upto/below that should work, try using ndk r8d, api level 14.

Comment: Thanks, qua-non. After some fruitless attempts at getting it all to work with the more latest NDK, and one of the more recent 8x NDKs, I switched to the pre-made Ubuntu installation. Might give my own Linux installation one more shot with one of the older NDKs, as you suggested.

Comment: Fixes for r9, API18 went in to py4a, buildozer so you should be able to use r9 now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In accordance with the above suggestion of downgrading the API and NDK (to 14 and r8c, respectively), I've downgraded the android tools, and the problem seems to have been resolved. Thanks!